# what is window.addFlags(Integer.MIN_VALUE)

Tags: java, android, window

I want to know what the following lines of code do?

```
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: What programming language and UI framework is this?

Comment: @Raymond Chen Android (java)